# Why do my org DEADLINEs appear with no warning?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I have `org-deadline-warning-days` set to 14.  Here is a deadline in my agenda file:

```
** TODO Do thing
DEADLINE: <2018-11-20 Wed>
```

In the agenda view for that date (20th Nov), I see:

```
next:       Deadline:   TODO Do thing
```

But no warning of that: for example, nothing on the 6th Nov.  I expected that having `org-deadline-warning-days` would show a warning on that day.  Why doesn't it?  How can I get a warning?

PS: even if I write the deadline like this:

```
DEADLINE: <2018-11-20 Wed -1d>
```

I still don't get any warning (which if I understand should show on the 19th in the agenda view in this case), only an entry in the agenda view on the 20th itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning only appears when the day of the warning comes around.  Before that date becomes today's date, it's not shown.

On a more careful reading of the manual, that's exactly what it says:

[Deadlines and Scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling)

> In addition, the agenda for **today** will carry a warning about the
> approaching or missed deadline

(my emphasis)