# How to see deadline reminders on days other than "today" in `org-agenda-day-view`?

Tags: org-agenda, deadline

I am using org-agenda to see my day (`org-agenda-day-view`). In the current day, I can see the *"deadline-warning-line"* with the corresponding `n` days left for the due date. Good.

However, when I press `f` to see tomorrow or `b`   to see yesterday, those days don't have any *"deadline-warning-line"*. (If I go further in the future to the due date, that day is properly marked.)

The answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45647/why-do-my-org-deadlines-appear-with-no-warning) shades a good light on the issue, saying that the warning is placed by emacs just on "today". The answer points to the manual, but does not state whether it is doable or not.

In `org-agenda-day-view`, I would like to see the *"deadline-warning-line"* in every day according to the values in `org-deadline-warning-days` and `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled` (which in my case is `pre-scheduled`).

Is there a practical way to achieve this?

Comment: It's hard code in `org-agenda-get-deadlines` and not easy to change. The most convenient way is change `(today? (org-agenda-today-p date)) ; DATE bound by calendar.` in `org-agenda-get-deadlines` to `(today? t)`, but there is an side effect that it will show `In 0 d.` rather than `Deadline:` on deadline day. If you want perfect version, you should change function logic at every place `today?` appear.

Comment: I see. I am *solar systems* far from being lisp savvy... so I think I will just live with it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @TianshuWang , you might want to make your comment into an answer. It adds new (and IMO correct) information to the answer in the linked question and *might* be useful to somebody in the future.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the reminder, I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic is hard coded in `org-agenda-get-deadlines` and not easy to change. The most convenient way is to change `(today? (org-agenda-today-p date)) ; DATE bound by calendar.` in `org-agenda-get-deadlines` to `(today? t)`, but there is a side effect that it will show `In 0 d.`  rather than `Deadline:`  on the deadline day. If you want the perfect version, you should change function logic at every place `today?` appears.